# SQLITE_BUSY with in-memory DB and SQLiteCPP library

Tags: c++, sqlite

With this very simple C++ program below (simplified from the real thing) I get:

```
test: ./SQLiteCpp-3.3.0/src/Database.cpp:92: void SQLite::Database::Deleter::operator()(sqlite3*): Assertion `0 == ret && "database is locked"' failed.
Aborted (core dumped)
```

This happens when the library attempts to close the connection to the database using `sqlite3_close()` in the destructor of `Database`.

In fact, the value of `ret` is SQLITE_BUSY (5). The SQLITE docs indicate that this is usually to another process/thread having a connection to the same db, however you can see that this is not the case here.

main.cpp:

```
#include "nl.hpp"
int main()
{
    auto nl = new NL();
    delete nl;  // Here only to illustrate the problem.
}
```

nl.hpp:

```
#include "SQLiteCpp/SQLiteCpp.h"
using namespace std;
class NL
{
public:
    NL();
    unique_ptr<SQLite::Statement> sqlst_insert_net;
    optional<SQLite::Database> db;
    void compile_sql_statements();
    void create_db();

};
```

nl.cpp:

```
#include <nl.hpp>

NL::NL() {
    this->create_db();
    this->compile_sql_statements();
}

void NL::create_db() {
    this->db.emplace(SQLite::Database(":memory:", SQLite::OPEN_READWRITE | SQLite::OPEN_CREATE));

    this->db->exec(
        "CREATE TABLE net(id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY, name TEXT UNIQUE);"
    );
}

void NL::compile_sql_statements() {
    this->sqlst_insert_net = make_unique<SQLite::Statement>(
        *(this->db), "INSERT INTO net (name) VALUES (?)");
}
```

Some things that seem to play a role here are:

- If I remove `delete nl;` the problem does not occur. I'm not a C++ expert but I would imagine that the `nl` object gets destroyed anyway at the end of `main()`, right?
- If I don't prepare the statements, by simply removing `this->compile_sql_statements();` from the constructor of `NL` the problem does not occur.

The two things above are necessary though. This is just a very simplified code just to replicate the problem. The instance of `NL` is held in a `shared_pointer` in the real program, so the destructor is necessarily called eventually. And the prepared statements are needed as well.

I've used seemingly identical code before and I didn't have this problem.

**Edit: Additional info.**

Here is the stack trace:

```
SQLite::Database::Deleter::operator()(SQLite::Database::Deleter * const this, sqlite3 * apSQLite) (.../SQLiteCpp-3.3.0/src/Database.cpp:92)
std::unique_ptr<sqlite3, SQLite::Database::Deleter>::~unique_ptr(std::unique_ptr<sqlite3, SQLite::Database::Deleter> * const this) (/usr/include/c++/9/bits/unique_ptr.h:292)
SQLite::Database::~Database(SQLite::Database * const this) (.../SQLiteCpp-3.3.0/include/SQLiteCpp/Database.h:264)
std::_Optional_payload_base<SQLite::Database>::_M_destroy(std::_Optional_payload_base<SQLite::Database> * const this) (/usr/include/c++/9/optional:257)
std::_Optional_payload_base<SQLite::Database>::_M_reset(std::_Optional_payload_base<SQLite::Database> * const this) (/usr/include/c++/9/optional:277)
std::_Optional_payload<SQLite::Database, false, false, false>::~_Optional_payload(std::_Optional_payload<SQLite::Database, false, false, false> * const this) (/usr/include/c++/9/optional:398)
std::_Optional_base<SQLite::Database, false, false>::~_Optional_base(std::_Optional_base<SQLite::Database, false, false> * const this) (/usr/include/c++/9/optional:471)
std::optional<SQLite::Database>::~optional(std::optional<SQLite::Database> * const this) (/usr/include/c++/9/optional:656)
NL::~NL(NL * const this) (.../src/nl.hpp:8)
main() (.../src/test.cpp:5)
```

And the function where the assertion fails (Database.cpp from SQLiteCpp):

```cpp
// Deleter functor to use with smart pointers to close the SQLite database connection in an RAII fashion.
void Database::Deleter::operator()(sqlite3* apSQLite)
{
    const int ret = sqlite3_close(apSQLite); // Calling sqlite3_close() with a nullptr argument is a harmless no-op.

    // Avoid unreferenced variable warning when build in release mode
    (void) ret;

    // Only case of error is SQLITE_BUSY: "database is locked" (some statements are not finalized)
    // Never throw an exception in a destructor :
    SQLITECPP_ASSERT(SQLITE_OK == ret, "database is locked");  // See SQLITECPP_ENABLE_ASSERT_HANDLER
}
```

As I mentioned, `ret==5 (SQLITE_BUSY)`.

This is wrapper library: [SQLiteC++](https://github.com/SRombauts/SQLiteCpp)

**Edit: Additional information.**

As suggested in the comments, the statement is not properly terminated. The destructor shown here (where `sqlite3_finalize(stmt)` is) is never called:

```
// Prepare SQLite statement object and return shared pointer to this object
Statement::TStatementPtr Statement::prepareStatement()
{
    sqlite3_stmt* statement;
    const int ret = sqlite3_prepare_v2(mpSQLite, mQuery.c_str(), static_cast<int>(mQuery.size()), &statement, nullptr);
    if (SQLITE_OK != ret)
    {
        throw SQLite::Exception(mpSQLite, ret);
    }
    return Statement::TStatementPtr(statement, [](sqlite3_stmt* stmt)
        {
            sqlite3_finalize(stmt);
        });
}
```

`TStatementPtr` is a shared_pointer that exists in `Statement`. The destructor of `Statement` is just the default. So it seems that the `Statement` in not being destroyed.

Comment: No. `nl` does not get destroyed if it isn't manually deleted before the end of the program. The memory and system resources will be reclaimed when the process ends, but the destructor will not be run and whatever work it does will go undone. If the destructor needs to set a "clean bit" in the database, move the robot arm to a known and safe position, or something like that, it won't happen.

Comment: Consider  `NL nl;` as a safer alternative to `auto nl = new NL(); delete nl;` As an automatic variable `nl`'s lifespan will be managed for you automatically. This will mirror your real-world case with the smart pointer a bit better.

Comment: If you step through this with the debugger does the error occur during the `NL` destructor?

Comment: I'm not familiar with that wrapper library but it's probably calling `sqlite3_close()` on the database before calling `sqlite3_stmt_finish()` on the prepared statements. (It really should be using `sqlite3_close_v2()` instead which doesn't return an error in that case)

Comment: Segmentation faults are usually really easy to catch in a debugger.. going from there to the cause should be fairly easy.

Comment: @user4581301, yes, it happens in the destructor. Please see my edit.

Comment: @jesper-juhl, It's not a segmentation fault, it's due to an assertion. I added the stack trace and the function where it happens.

Comment: @Shawn, you pointed me in the right direction. Please see my own answer. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue happened to be quite subtle. As suggested by @Shawn in the comments to the question, the prepared statement was not being finalized by the time the connection to the database was closed. In fact the destructor of the `Statement` should have invoked `sqlite3_finalize(stmt)`, but it was never called. This happened because the `~Database` was invoked first.

This was simply because of the order in which the `Statement` and the `Database` were declared in `NL`. This determines the order in which members are destroyed.

Declaring the `Database` first, then the `Statement` causes the `Statement` to be destroyed first, solving the problem.